# How to make multiple checkboxes work with php and sql

Tags: php, sql, checkbox

How would I pass an array of multiple checkboxes and values through php, saving to a sql database, as well as being able to pull up the saved data back on the client side?

For example, I have an array that saves checkbox values in the way of '"checked"""checked""""', but not only do I want to save the checked value, I also want to save the form data, as follows :

- Apples : Checked
- Oranges : Not Checked
- Bananas : Checked
- Tomatoes :   Checked

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, please answer with context of how to do, not just code - still learning!

Here is the code THAT WORKS for this question

processing code :

```
$salesman = $data['data-invoice-salesman']; // this is an array
                $salesman_array = array(); // create new array
                $salesman_names = array(1 => "User1",2 => "User2",3 => "User3",4 => "User4",5 => "User");
                for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){ // loop from 1 to 5
                if(in_array($i, $salesman)){ // if value exists (has been selected), stack 'checked', if not, stack ''.
                    $salesman_array[$salesman_names[$i]] = "checked";
                } else {
                    $salesman_array[$salesman_names[$i]] = "";
                }
                }
                $salesman_json = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, json_encode($salesman_array)); // encode the array into JSON and then escape it.
```

form code THAT WORKS :

```
<?php
        $salesmand = json_decode($invoice['Invoice']['salesman'], true);
        $salesman_names = array(1 => "User1",2 => "User2",3 => "User3",4 => "User4",5 => "User5");
            foreach ($salesman_names AS $i => $name) {
                if ($salesman[$name] == "checked") {
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'" checked/> '.$name.'<br>';
                } else {
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'" /> '.$name.'<br>';
                }
            }
        ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: `$data['data-invoice-salesman']` should be `$_POST['data-invoice-salesman']`. Other than that, it looks like it should work. Although storing JSON strings in a database doesn't seem like a great idea.

Comment: @Barmar It works to save the checkbox value, not the name of each input.  Why would storing JSON strings be a bad idea(they are escaped)?

Comment: IT's not a security issue, just a general database design problem. You can't easily search for a particular value, for instance.

Comment: the "LIKE" search function will not sieve the results?

Comment: It can, but it's a very poor way to do it. It can't take advantage of an index. Learn about proper database normalization.

Comment: If I do a large scale database with a crudton of operations against it, I will keep that in mind.  Users may utilize the search 1-2x daily...

Comment: Just found out that my code only saves the checked value on the last checkbox, and still does not save the name, for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an array that maps the indexes to the name:

```
$salesman_names = array(
    1 => "Joe Smith",
    2 => "Fred Flintston",
    3 => "George Jetson",
    4 => "John Hamm",
    5 => "Alan Smithee"
);
```

Then in your loop, you can do:

```
$salesman_array[$salesan_names[$i]] = "checked";
```

The JSON that's saved in the database might then look like:

```
{"Joe Smith":"checked", "Fred Flintson": "", "George Jetson","checked", "John Hamm":"", "Alan Smithee":""}
```

To display the checkboxes, you would refer to the `$salesman_array` when displaying it:

```
$salesman = json_decode($invoice['Invoice']['salesman'], true);
foreach ($salesman_names AS $i => $name) {
    if ($salesman[$name] == "checked") {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'" checked/> '.$name.'<br>';
    } else {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'" /> '.$name.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: would I not need another column in my db called "products"?

Comment: I don't really understand your application. This is what you said the names of the checkboxes are, but then your PHP loop calls them salesmen.

Comment: Sorry, the fruit example had nothing to do with my code, my actual code will have 5 salesman names, as well as need the capability to save/retrieve the salesman, and the status of the checkbox

Comment: do i replace my $i = $k+1; code with the $salesman array?  can you include placement of where your code fits in with mine?

Comment: Added that to the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99435/discussion-between-steven-and-barmar).